# Multipeer Connectivity crash when inviting peer that stopped advertising

Tags: objective-c, ios7, multipeer-connectivity

I have the following scenario:

- Peer **A** is waiting for invitations in a custom UI (let's call it `WaitingVC`). The `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser` object is initialized at application start, and the advertising starts (`startAdvertisingPeer`) when the `WaitingVC` is presented.
- Peer **B** has the `MCNearbyServiceBrowser` up and running, also with custom UI (that is, not using the Apple provided `MCBrowserViewController`).
- Peer **B** finds Peer **A** (`browser:foundPeer:withDiscoveryInfo:` is called).
- Meanwhile Peer **A** chooses to close the `WaitingVC`. Advertising is stopped (`stopAdvertisingPeer`).
- There is a few seconds lag, before Peer **B** finds out, that Peer **A** is lost (that is, `browser:lostPeer:` is called).
- If in these few seconds, Peer **B** chooses to invite Peer **A** (who still seems to be available for Peer **B**), Peer **A** crashes (yes, the invited one, who normally stopped advertising).
- Peer **B**'s invite normally times out, and no problem arises.

The crash happens in queue `com.apple.NSNetServices.tcplistener-queue`. A `dispatch_call_block_and_release` call fails at release (`EXC_BREAKPOINT`).

I truly wonder, if this a bug in the MC framework; or am I missing some cleanup procedure? Peer **A** only does the following:

- App delegate: Creating an `MCPeerID`, store in a strong property,
- App delegate: Creating an `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser`, store in a strong property, setting delegate,
- In `WaitingVC`: calling `startAdvertisingPeer`, then calling `stopAdvertisingPeer` when done.

The crash seemingly occurs no matter what I do. If the `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser` object and the `MCPeerID` object is being kept in `WaitingVC` and thus destroyed after the `WaitingVC` is closed, the crash still happens.

Apart from this, everything works fine (invitation procedure, connecting, exchanging data); but this few seconds window for certain failure is not really acceptable. Keeping the advertiser running all the time solves this, but it's just treating the symtpom (and this "sync" feature would be used seldom in the applicaiton, so it's also an overkill).

**Update:**

The same crash happens when using `MCAdvertiserAssistant`, if I call its `stop` method on Peer **A**, and quickly connect on Peer **B**. Also, I tested the scenario on this tutorial: http://techmaster.vn/2013/09/multipeer-connectivity-quick-tutorial/ - and the result is the same: Crash. So I have a strong suspicion, this is a bug on Apple's side...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been experiencing the same crash and according to this thread in the Dev Forums so have other people. A bug report has been created for it:

[Developer Forums: Multipeer Connectivity Crash](https://devforums.apple.com/message/907710)

Comment: This is it, seems it's really a bug on Apple's side. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple workaround. I added a delay before starting the browser going.

To fill in the whole story I created a wrapper to replace GKSession with MCSession. The connection was being closed and reopened under specific circumstances, by both ends at the same time, hence it crashed. Adding a delay to the browser start offset it from the tear down of the other end avoiding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with your delegate callback

```
advertiser:didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:withContext:invitationHandler:
```

most likely with the final argument, the invitationHandler block. Is this method being called? When B makes A crash, there must be something that is being called and this seems to be the only conceivable entry point.

Comment: This delegate callback was amongst the suspects, but nope, it's not called.

Comment: Then it might have to do with the attempt to call it - maybe because it is looking for a `nil` delegate?

Comment: The delegate is not `nil`'d; everything is intact, only the `stopAdvertisingPeer` is called.